# npm ls matching a pattern?

Tags: node.js, npm, redux

I just installed a couple of packages to start working with [Redux](http://redux.js.org/):

```
npm install --no-optional --save-dev redux-devtools
npm install --no-optional --save react-redux
```

Then I wanted to make sure everything is installed, so I checked with [`npm ls`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls):

```
$ npm ls react redux
MyProject@ /home/me/projects/myproject
├── react@15.3.0 
└── redux@3.5.2
```

Yeah, they are here!

However, I wonder if there is a way to check all the packages starting with `re`. Both of these commands:

```
npm ls re*
npm ls re
```

Returned the same error:

```
MyProject@ /home/me/projects/myproject
└── (empty)

npm ERR! code 1
```

I thought [`npm search`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/search) could make it, but as I understand it looks for available packages, not only the ones that you have installed in your machine.

```
$ npm search re*
NAME             DESCRIPTION                                           AUTHOR   
requirements-txt requirements-txt - generate requirements.txt (python… =russiani
```

So: is there a way with `npm ls` to provide a pattern to check the packages that are installed and match it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about piping to `grep`?

```
$ npm ls | grep 'lod.*'
   └── lodash@3.5.0
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good one! I though, though, that `npm ls` would have some kind of globbing option, like [`ls`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) has.